# How to display images from AWS S3 without downloading in the local storage

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

My android app shows images which is downloaded from `AWS S3`.  For now I download the images to the local storage, and show images from the downloaded images. 
But, it would be annoying from the user's perspective.

How can I display image from `AWS S3` without downloading into the local storage.  It would be great if I can display images not with the file but with image url.

It might be possible by set the files on `ASW S3` to public, which I want to avoid for security issues.

Comment: Please use Glide or Piccaso library to display image from URL you get from the server.

Comment: Use the AWS S3 API to generate a signed URL. You should then be able to pass that URL to your favorite image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks so much for the reply. Can u share some reference for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly generate pre-signed AWS S3 URL and then load image using Glide. Below are steps:

1. How to generate pre-signed AWS S3 bucket URL check [here](https://www.example-code.com/android/aws_pre_signed_url_v4.asp)
2. Load image using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

   ```
   Glide.with(getActivity().getBaseContext()).load("IMAGE URL FROM S3").centerCrop().into(imageView);
   ```